# Byzantine Agreement: Why does OM need f+1 rounds in a synchronous setting?

Tags: protocol-design

To get Byzantine Fault Tolerance in a synchronous model you can use an Oral Message Algorithm. For `n > 3f+1` it gets an Byzantine agreement in `f+1` rounds. Why `f+1`?

Answer (score 1):

I will use $m$, not $f$  according the original paper.  It gets an Byzantine agreement in $m+1$ rounds.

The paper [the byzantine generals problem](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs174/byzantine.pdf)       says:

> THEOREM 1. For any m, Algorithm OM (m ) satisfies conditions IC1 and IC2
>   if there are more than 3m generals and at most m traitors.

Since it is a recursive algorithm, 
from  $OM(0)$ to $OM(m)$, so it is $m+1$ rounds.